# How to display git commit inside React-Native app?

Tags: git, react-native, github

I am working on management app in which there is a requirement to show git commits of user inside the application so that the manager can see and assess the same.

Is there any way to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the Github API in order to get the commit messages.

The docs can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#commits)